# kdb+: group by and sum over multiple columns

Tags: kdb

Consider the following data:

```
table:

time          colA    colB     colC
-----------------------------------
11:30:04.194  31      250      a
11:30:04.441  31      280      a
11:30:14.761  31.6    100      a
11:30:21.324  34      100      a
11:30:38.991  32      100      b
11:31:20.968  32      100      b
11:31:56.922  32.2    1000     b
11:31:57.035  32.6    5000     c
11:32:05.810  33      100      c
11:32:05.810  33      100      a
11:32:14.461  32      300      b
```

Now how can I `sum` `colB` whenever `colC` is the same, without losing the time order.

So the output would be:

```
first time    avgA    sumB     colC
-----------------------------------
11:30:04.194  31.2    730      a
11:30:38.991  32.07   1200     b
11:31:57.035  32.8    5100     c
11:32:05.810  33      100      a
11:32:14.461  32      300      b
```

What I have so far:

```
select by time from (select first time, avg colA, sum colB by colC, time from table)
```

But the output is not grouped by `colC`. How should the query look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
get select first time, avg colA, sum colB, first colC by sums colC<>prev colC from table
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different way to achieve this using `differ` :

```
value select  first time, avg colA, sum colB , first colC by g:(sums differ colC) from table
```